Template CMS and Astro
Issue occurs on building project because a schema which looks correct to me. Other parts of site are working. Aiming to run this template https://github.com/cassidoo/blahg
This error I getting
Expected to host website online on Netflix with CMS functionaling. It passes CMS Keys but stuck on schema
